# Python/Tkinter/PIL - Scale doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

Coding my simple image viewer, where I have an image and can modify its brightness and contrast by scales, I came to problem with Enhance class that I can't solve. It doesn't give me any error, but it doesn't work as I want. I want simply the scale to adjust brightness when I move with it. I haven't implemented second Enhance class, just want to make the first Enhance class and scale work on the image. Thank you :)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageEnhance

class ImageViewer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="green")

        # for now, don't use images. 
        self.im = Image.open("plant.jpg") #choose your picture
        self.tkim = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)

        # these three widgets make up our main layout
        label = tk.Label(self, image=self.tkim, text="label")
        e = Enhance(self,self.im, ImageEnhance.Brightness)
        e1 = Enhance1(self, self.im)

        label.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        e.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        e1.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)


class Enhance(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master,image, enhancer):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.image = image
        self.tkim = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.mode, image.size)
        self.enhancer = enhancer(image)

        self.update_enhance("1.0")
        s = tk.Scale(self, label="Brightness", orient=tk.VERTICAL,from_=3.0, to=-1.0, resolution=0.01,command=self.update_enhance)
        s.set(self.value)
        s.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", expand = True)

    def update_enhance(self, value):
        self.value = eval(value)
        self.tkim.paste(self.enhancer.enhance(self.value))

    # width, height, and color are only temporary, they
    # make it easy to see the frames before they have
    # any content

class Enhance1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, image):
       self.image = image

# width, height, and color are only temporary, they
# make it easy to see the frames before they have
# any content
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="blue", width=100, height=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    ImageViewer(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create two image objects from a single image file. You are showing one image, but updating another.  In your `Enhance` class you are creating a second `self.tkim` instance and pasting your enhanced image to it, but that image isn't being displayed anywhere. The original image which *is* being displayed isn't being modified by your enhance function.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I can't find any way to fix it.

Comment: @Chilcone: what do you mean by "can't find any way to fix it"? Did you try using only a single image and it didn't work, or that you don't know how to only use a single image?

Comment: That I don't know how to only use a single image. Sorry for my unspecific anwers.

Comment: @Chilcone: there's nothing tricky about it: just like you pass in the image, pass in the tkim instance as well: `e = Enhance(self,self.im, self.tkim, ImageEnhance.Brightness)`

Comment: So I've passed in the tkim instance, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It doesn't throw any error, but the scale is still not working.